# Complex mySQL query for getting three different tables comparison

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**I need to create very difficult SQL query, but I can't handle it myself. Maybe someone can help me or suggest some different approach.**

I have three tables:
[image: Table structures]

And I need to show table on the page that required next points:

- Compare every user points with admin's points (points.user_id=1)
- If the points are equal, then the user gets points according to the difference between date that the points are saved and the date that the game is held. If points are different, no points are added.
- I Can set how many points can the user get when the difference between two dates mentioned above are e.g. 2 days, 3 days etc. (if(games.date - points.date = 2days{points=points*2} or similar )
- Comparison take place after (games.date > now())

**UPDATE:**

```
$points = array();

$all_ifo = mysql_query("SELECT p.id, p.user_id, p.game_id, p.points, 
ABS(p.points - a.points) rating_diff, a.points, g.home, g.datetime, u.username
FROM points AS p 
JOIN points AS a ON p.game_id = a.game_id AND a.user_id = 1
JOIN games  AS g ON p.game_id = g.id
JOIN users  AS u ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE p.user_id != 1 AND g.datetime < NOW();") or die(mysql_error());

while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_ifo)){
    $points['' . $info['username'] . ''] += $info['rating_diff'];
    echo $info['p.id'];
}
asort($points);

echo "<table class='tabelid'><th>Test</th>";
foreach ($points as $key => $value) {
    $i++;
    echo "<tr><td>".$i.".</td><td style='width:250px;'>" . 
    ucfirst($key) . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

**UPDATE 2:**

So it was suggested that for the point counting I need a separate table. But it's quite complicated:

```
Game saved in 25-45 min after game start - 1 point
Game saved in 0 - 24 min after game start - 2 points
Game saved in on the same day but before the game - 4 points 
Game saved in 1 day before - 6 points
Game saved in 2 days before - 8 points
..
Game saved in 15 days before - 34 points
```

So any suggestions how the table should be done for implementing it easyly to the system afterwards? And how this rating_diff get the right point amount?

**UPDATE 3:**

```
$points = array();

$all_ifo = mysql_query("SELECT x.*, d.*
  FROM Extra AS x
  JOIN (SELECT p.id, p.user_id, p.game_id, p.points, p.date, a.points adminpoints, g.home,
               g.datetime, u.username, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, g.datetime, p.date) AS Offset
          FROM points AS p
          JOIN points AS a ON p.game_id = a.game_id AND a.user_id = 1
          JOIN games  AS g ON p.game_id = g.id
          JOIN users  AS u ON p.user_id = u.id
         WHERE p.user_id != 1
           AND g.datetime < NOW()
       ) AS d
    ON d.Offset >= x.LoOffsetFromGameTime
   AND d.Offset <  x.HiOffsetFromGameTime;") or die(mysql_error());

while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_ifo)){
    $points['' . $info['username'] . ''] += $info['Offset'];
    echo $info['p.id'];
    }

arsort($points);

echo "<table class='tabelid'><th>Test</th>";
foreach ($points as $key => $value) {
    $i++;
    echo "<tr><td>".$i.".</td><td style='width:250px;'>" . ucfirst($key) . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
```

For output I get the time difference between saved time and actual game time:

```
Test
1.  User1   1851
2.  User2   -502
```

But I don't know how to compare it with Extra table and therefore get the right points. Of course points should be added only if the points(0, 1 or 2) for the same game_id is same with admin's points (0, 1 or 2).

Comment: Please change the title to something that actually describes the problem.

Comment: Sorry! It was difficult to name it. Is it better now?

Comment: That's certainly better, thank you. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Minor tweaks to your SQL

Your current SQL, slightly reformatted, is:

```
SELECT p.id, g.home, p.user_id, u.username, p.points, p1.points, 
       ABS(p.points - p1.points) rating_diff
FROM points p 
JOIN games g ON p.game_id = p.id
JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id
JOIN points p1 ON p.game_id = p1.game_id AND p1.user_id = 1
WHERE u.id != 1 
ORDER BY g.id, ABS(p.points - p1.points)
```

This should be close to what you're after.  You've not included the game date criterion.  You say:

> Comparison take place after `(games.date > now())`.

That implies that the comparison takes place when the game is still scheduled in the future (because the game's timestamp is after the current timestamp, which is more normally termed 'before the game takes place' than 'after'.  I assume you should have `<` instead of `>`.

```
SELECT p.id, g.home, p.user_id, u.username, p.points, a.points, 
       ABS(p.points - a.points) rating_diff
  FROM points AS p 
  JOIN games  AS g ON p.game_id = p.id
  JOIN users  AS u ON p.user_id = u.id
  JOIN points AS a ON p.game_id = a.game_id AND a.user_id = 1
 WHERE u.id != 1
   AND g.`datetime` < NOW()
 ORDER BY g.id, ABS(p.points - a.points)
```

I've given the 'admin' record the alias 'a' instead of 'p1', keeping to single-letter aliases.  I've reluctantly used the back-ticks to treat `datetime` as a delimited identifier given that it is also a type.  I'm not certain it is necessary, but it probably is.

You haven't computed the extra points based on the date difference; it would probably be best to record that information in an extra table and make the appropriate to that.  However, since your outline scheme suggests only '2 days difference, double the points', it is hard to know what the design should be.  In particular, what should happen if the days difference is 0 or 1? Would the multiplier be fractional; is the result rounded up?  Is there an additive term?  Etc.

---

### TDQD — Test-Driven Query Design

If this is not producing the data you are after, go into TDQD (Test-Driven Query Design) mode.  Start with a simple query and demonstrate that it gets the correct information.  Then extend it, demonstrating that each query also works.

#### Non-Admin Points Records:

```
SELECT p.id, p.user_id, p.game_id, p.points
  FROM points AS p 
 WHERE p.user_id != 1;
```

Note that there's an immediate difference compared to what you have; since I'm not selecting from the Users table yet, that condition has to be translated from `u.id != 1` to `p.user_id != 1`.  This will carry forward.  It shouldn't affect the accuracy of the SQL, but TDQD has already given a slightly different query design.

#### Non-Admin Points Records with Corresponding Admin Record:

```
SELECT p.id, p.user_id, p.game_id, p.points, a.user_id, a.points
  FROM points AS p
  JOIN points AS a ON p.game_id = a.game_id AND a.user_id = 1
 WHERE p.user_id != 1;
```

#### Select Game Information too:

(I'm being lazy and not enclosing `datetime` in back-ticks.)

```
SELECT p.id, p.user_id, p.game_id, p.points, a.points, g.home, g.datetime
  FROM points AS p
  JOIN points AS a ON p.game_id = a.game_id AND a.user_id = 1
  JOIN games  AS g ON p.game_id = g.id
 WHERE p.user_id != 1;
```

#### Select historical game information only:

```
SELECT p.id, p.user_id, p.game_id, p.points, a.points, g.home, g.datetime
  FROM points AS p
  JOIN points AS a ON p.game_id = a.game_id AND a.user_id = 1
  JOIN games  AS g ON p.game_id = g.id
 WHERE p.user_id != 1
   AND g.datetime < NOW();
```

#### Add user information:

```
SELECT p.id, p.user_id, p.game_id, p.points, a.points, g.home, g.datetime, u.username
  FROM points AS p
  JOIN points AS a ON p.game_id = a.game_id AND a.user_id = 1
  JOIN games  AS g ON p.game_id = g.id
  JOIN users  AS u ON p.user_id = u.id
 WHERE p.user_id != 1
   AND g.datetime < NOW();
```

I could switch the WHERE condition back to `u.id != 1` now, but there's no benefit to doing so.

---

### Point Counting

Standard SQL supports INTERVAL types such as INTERVAL DAY TO MINUTE.  This represents an amount of elapsed time and would make it relatively simple to encode the table of points.  Note that this is hypothetical for MySQL — we'll deal with realities later.

```
CREATE TABLE Extra
(
    LoOffsetFromGameTime    INTERVAL DAY TO MINUTE NOT NULL,
    HiOffsetFromGameTime    INTERVAL DAY TO MINUTE NOT NULL,
    Points                  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CHECK(LoOffsetFromGameTime < HiOffSetFromGameTime)
);

INSERT INTO Extra VALUES ('-99 23:59', '-0 00:45',  0);
INSERT INTO Extra VALUES ('-0 00:45',  '-0 00:24',  1);
INSERT INTO Extra VALUES ('-0 00:24',  '0 00:00',   2);
INSERT INTO Extra VALUES ('0 00:00',   '1 00:00',   4);
INSERT INTO Extra VALUES ('1 00:00',   '2 00:00',   6);
INSERT INTO Extra VALUES ('2 00:00',   '3 00:00',   8);
...
INSERT INTO Extra VALUES ('15 00:00',  '99 23:59', 34);
```

The ranges are 'open-closed'; the low value is included, the high value is excluded.  This means that the BETWEEN AND operator cannot be used; it implements 'open-open' ranges, including both end points.

The '-99 days' and '+99 days' values can be increased if need so be; the default number of digits in the day portion of INTERVAL DAY TO MINUTE is 2, but you can specify more if you need more.  The queries below assume that the difference between game time and entry time will always be in exactly one of the rows in the table.

#### Selecting extra points too

Pretending that we can use this table, then the query for extra points becomes:

```
SELECT p.id, p.user_id, p.game_id, p.points, a.points, g.home, g.datetime, u.username
  FROM points AS p
  JOIN points AS a ON p.game_id = a.game_id AND a.user_id = 1
  JOIN games  AS g ON p.game_id = g.id
  JOIN users  AS u ON p.user_id = u.id
  JOIN extra  AS x
    ON CAST(g.datetime - p.date AS INTERVAL DAY TO MINUTE) >= x.LoOffsetFromGameTime
   AND CAST(g.datetime - p.date AS INTERVAL DAY TO MINUTE) <  x.HiOffsetFromGameTime
 WHERE p.user_id != 1
   AND g.datetime < NOW();
```

That's fairly clumsy with that repeated expression; we should make what was previously the main query into a sub-query which selects the value and gives it a name, and then use that in the join with the Extra table:

```
SELECT x.*, d.*
  FROM extra  AS x
  JOIN (SELECT p.id, p.user_id, p.game_id, p.usr_points, a.adm_points, g.home,
               g.datetime, u.username,
               CAST(g.datetime - NOW() AS INTERVAL DAY TO MINUTE) AS Offset
          FROM points AS p
          JOIN points AS a ON p.game_id = a.game_id AND a.user_id = 1
          JOIN games  AS g ON p.game_id = g.id
          JOIN users  AS u ON p.user_id = u.id
         WHERE p.user_id != 1
           AND g.datetime < NOW()
       ) AS d
    ON d.Offset >= x.LoOffsetFromGameTime
   AND d.Offset <  x.HiOffsetFromGameTime;
```

If I've interpreted the conditions correctly and not inverted anything, then this should get you the information you need.

#### But MySQL doesn't support INTERVAL types

I will assume that 'switch to a DBMS that does support INTERVAL types' isn't an option.

Logically, the simplest mechanism at run time is to treat the difference between two date values as an appropriate integer number of minutes.  You can then encode the INTERVAL DAY TO MINUTE as the appropriate number of minutes instead, but the data entry for the table is messier:

```
CREATE TABLE Extra
(
    LoOffsetFromGameTime    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    HiOffsetFromGameTime    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Points                  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CHECK(LoOffsetFromGameTime < HiOffSetFromGameTime)
);

INSERT INTO Extra VALUES (-2000000,      -45,  0);
INSERT INTO Extra VALUES (     -45,      -24,  1);
INSERT INTO Extra VALUES (     -24,        0,  2);
INSERT INTO Extra VALUES (       0,    +1440,  4);
INSERT INTO Extra VALUES (   +1440,    +2880,  6);
INSERT INTO Extra VALUES (   +2880,    +4320,  8);
...
INSERT INTO Extra VALUES (  +21600, +2000000, 34);
```

I'm using 2,000,000 as a convenient 'big' number; you can specify ±2,147,483,647 instead, or any other suitable range.

Note that you should validate the Extra table for continuous coverage and no overlaps in the data.  I didn't specify a primary key because there isn't a particularly good option to choose.  You really want the open-closed range of the two offset columns as the primary key (with constraints on continuousness and non-overlap), but that isn't expressible in SQL (or, not easily, and not as a primary key constraint).

Then you just need to write the difference between game time and NOW() as the appropriate number of minutes.  Indeed, it might be even easier to work with seconds, though it complicates the data entry for the table that little bit more.  OTOH, you won't be encoding the table very often, and you can always arrange to use a procedure that takes a convenient representation and converts that into seconds for you.

However, the [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) may do exactly what we need.  I haven't worked through the implications of what its return type is.  There are lots of other functions to choose from, and somewhere in amongst them all, you'll be able to get a convenient expression that returns the difference between the game time and the user's entry time as an appropriate value that can be joined cleanly with the Extra table, yielding the required answer.

---

### Adding Extra Points (Update 3)

The number of points to be added is `x.points` if `d.usr_points = d.adm_points`, so we can simply write that in the select-list:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN d.usr_points = d.adm_points THEN x.points ELSE 0 END AS added_points,
       x.*, d.*
  FROM ...
```

Comment: You're a god! :) Thank you so much! But offcourse I need more help. I updated my question, can you please take a look!

Comment: Thanks! It was very educative and I really appreciate your help, but could you take a look my **Update 3** ? I'm so close for getting it work as I want (of course with your help)

Comment: @Algeron: I've added a little bit more that addresses, I think, your residual issue.  It looks like you're getting plausible numbers out of TIMESTAMPDIFF, so the bulk of the hard work was done for us, courtesy of the function.  If you need to, you can do TDQD on just the Extra table and something simple that specifies various numbers of minutes before or after game time, to check that you see the correct row from Extra for the given number of minutes.

Comment: Seems like I got my system working. I can't thank you enough! :) But in the future if I find myself in trouble regarding to SQL I know with whom I should contact! Once again! THANKS!